# Moving from NetBeans 7 RC2 to 7.0.1

Tags: java, netbeans

So, I've used the NetBeans 7 Release Candidate for a while now (and it's worked great). Today I realized 7.0.1 had already been released, so I downloaded it. However, upon opening 7.0.1, it only gave me the option to import my NB 6.9 settings, not my 7 RC2 settings. Does anyone know where the NB settings are stored (I'm on Mac OS X, BTW) so I can move them manually? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No one seemed to be able to answer me, and as far as I can tell, it isn't possible. I was forced to reconfigure NetBeans manually.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your C drive.
Click on users.
Go in your main Username.
Click on a folder called Documents.
You should see Netbeans Projects. You should find them there.

Comment: I know that, but those are just my projects. I mean things like my configuration. Normally they'd just be in the AppData/Library folders, but NetBeans seems to store its data elsewhere.